# How to get user input in Node.js with callback functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-input

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let greetings = (name) => {
    window.alert(`hello ${name}`);
}

let processUserInput = (callback) => {
    readline.question("Who are you? ", input => {
        callback(input);
        readline.close();
    });
}

processUserInput(greetings);
```

So I read this page on how to get user input in Node.js with a reference to callback functions and decided to try something out. I wanted to merge these two blocks of code into one, but failed and the console threw an error.

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

readline.question('Who are you?', name => {
  console.log(`Hey there ${name}!`);
  readline.close();
});
```

```
function greeting(name) {
  alert(`Hello, ${name}`);
}

function processUserInput(callback) {
  const name = prompt("Please enter your name.");
  callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting);
```

```
node:internal/readline/emitKeypressEvents:74
            throw err;
            ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at greetings (/Users/*/Documents/vscode/09/temp.js:7:5)
    at /Users/*/Documents/vscode/09/temp.js:12:9
    at [_onLine] [as _onLine] (node:internal/readline/interface:421:7)
    at [_line] [as _line] (node:internal/readline/interface:894:18)
    at [_ttyWrite] [as _ttyWrite] (node:internal/readline/interface:1272:22)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (node:internal/readline/interface:271:20)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at emitKeys (node:internal/readline/utils:357:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
    at ReadStream.onData (node:internal/readline/emitKeypressEvents:64:36)
```

I really don't know what to make of it so I'm posting the question here.

Reference:
https://www.codecademy.com/article/getting-user-input-in-node-js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

I was expecting a normal output like "hello *"

Comment: See [Differences between Node.js and the Browser](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser/https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser/). In Node.js, you don't have `document`, `window` or certain other objects that are provided by a browser.

Comment: @jarmod I was working in a browser forgot to change `window.alert()` to `console.log()` when I switched to Node.js, and now everything works fine. Thanks man!